# How does C/CPP know how to point to "next" struct node when the struct node is not yet defined?

Tags: c++, c, struct, linked-list

When creating singly linked lists, it is common to create a Node struct as follows:

```
struct node { 
    int data; 
    struct node *next; 
}
```

However, I was wondering how does the pointer to the next node `next` knows what struct `node` is if `node`'s definition has not been done yet.

I have read from [quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-nodes-in-a-linked-list-are-declared-as-pointer-itself-Nodes-contains-a-pointer-part-inside-it-to-link-other-node-then-why-node-is-itself-declared-as-pointer) that the compiler fails to compile the following:

```
struct node { 
    int data; 
    struct node next; 
};
```

giving the following error:

```
a.c:6:13: error: field has incomplete type 'struct node' 
struct node next; 
            ^ 
a.c:4:8: note: definition of 'struct node' is not complete until the closing '}' 
struct node { 
       ^ 
1 error generated.
```

If the definition of `node` struct is not done before '}' is used, then how come can we set the pointer to an undefined user-defined data type `node`?

Comment: You don't need a complete type to have a pointer to that type.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `next` is a *pointer* to `node`, the type does not need to be complete in order for compilation to succeed.

Consider also a simple example in C++. The type of `A` does not need to be complete in order to have a pointer to it in struct `B`. Be prepared to see this pattern used to resolve circular dependencies.

```cpp
struct A;

struct B {
    A *c;
};

struct A {
    B *d;
};
```

Please note that C and C++ are two distinct programming languages, and while specific chunks of C code *may* be valid C++, it is not guaranteed that it *will be*, or even that if it is, that it will behave with exactly the same semantics.

Comment: Thank you for your examples! I could see how it works. But still, the only reasoning I could make to understand this would be that "pointers", in general, are of fixed size. Only then, I would think that no matter what the size of the data that this pointer is pointing to, the pointer will only need to store a fixed size bits. Am I on the right track? Do pointers have fixed length size?

Comment: You are thinking correctly. As `node` is not complete, it can't know how much space to include for a `node`, but it can know how much space the pointer will take. You can also consider the implications of a `node` containing a `node` that would presumably contain a `node` which would contain a `node`... and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify more, can I assume that sizeof(int*) == sizeof(char*) == sizeof(pointer to any_user_defined_type)? The whole concept would only make sense to me if the pointer size is independent of the data type that it is trying to point at...

Comment: @tyson_the_13th: The C standard does not generally require different pointer types to have the same size. Pointers to `void` and to character types must have the same size as each other. Pointers to structures must have the same size as each other. Points to unions must have the same size as each other. Pointers to compatible types and qualified versions of them must have the same size as each other. Other than that, sizes of pointers may vary. This is specified in C 2018 6.2.5 28.

Answer (score 5):

It does not need to know. A pointer is just an address. In your struct, when you define the next attribute, the compiler will reserve enough space inside the struct to keep an address. It does not need to know the full structure.

This:

```
struct node { 
    int data; 
    struct node next; 
};
```

cannot compile because the compiler cannot determine the size of the node struct. The size of the struct is equal with the size of the struct plus the size of an int.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean, so am I allowed to think that pointers in general have fixed size which is equal to the size required to store an address?

Comment: Even if this would be legal C code, it would result in a structure of infinite size, because `struct node` contains a `struct node` which contains a `struct node` which conains a `struct node` etc.

Comment: Yes. All pointers have the same size and are capable of holding an address. You need the type of the pointer only to deference it. When you type a->foo you need to know the type of the pointer in order to compute where foo is stored. From the type, you know the offset of foo within the struct. So, a->foo means, add the offset to foo to the value of pointer a and grab what is stored there based on the type of foo.